# rounding issue with typecast<int>

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with a typecast conversion when calculating the tip amount.

```
const double TIP_PERCENTAGE = .15;

cout << static_cast<int>(TIP_PERCENTAGE * 100.00);

return 0;
```

I  am getting 14 instead of .15 x 100 = 15 and then converted into an int of 15. I can tell that it is truncating the answer, but I'm not sure why or how it's getting a value less than 15 such as 14.999 etc.

Comment: Floating point numbers like these of type `double` are not infinitely precise due to how they are stored in memory, thats why you may get eg. 0.149999998 instead of 0.15.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense as they are not binary relatable as I am finding out.

Comment: Another option is to use binary coded decimal (BCD) numbers, which can represent fixed-point numbers in decimal exactly.  But for many platforms, they are not the popular choice.  At the risk of being mistaken... Standard C++ does not come with BCD support, but there are third party BCD libraries for C and C++ available.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get rid of this issue would be to use `std::round` before casting to int:

```
static_cast<int>(std::round(TIP_PERCENTAGE * 100.0))
```

Comment: that fixed it! 
Thank you!